# Serving files with php without worrying about process limit

Tags: php

In my context, I need to serve several videos to my clients. Because of this, I'm doing URL rewriting to redirect access to those files to a PHP script. The PHP script authenticates users and serves the files appropriately, even releasing the session and setting time limit to 0 (i.e. no time limit) before using *readfile* to serve it.

Things would work just fine, except for a global limit on the number of concurrent PHP processes.
Now, just a handful of users watching videos is enough to make my website queue other requests, making them wait for the videos to be completely served to the people watching them.

Sadly, I'm using a shared hosting service, which does not have mod_xsendfile installed. Needless to say, I can't tune the maximum number of PHP processes, and that wouldn't be a good solution anyway.

I'm out of ideas and I practically don't have any experience with PHP. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you need that sort of capability my suggestion would be to move onto your own server, or better yet put your video on CDNA that supports streaming your your application server doesn't need to mess with serving up streaming video at all.

Comment: That might be an option if I can't find a solution with what I have. My hosting service allows me to use Python and Ruby. Perhaps some form of asynchronous programming where one process serves videos for all users is possible with those?